# Bubbles restart after 1 month?

Tags: airlock, primary, bubble

i've done 4 batches one month ago, one per day, day after day.

My batches now are of 60L, and I use 2 30L fermenters for each batch. 2 of the 4 batches are the "same recipe", so I have 4 fermenters in "same conditions".

So, bubbles stopped a long ago, there's no activity on any fermenter, beside 1 of them.

What could be happening to it to restart to bubble? It can be a sign of too much time in primary? Never take so much time in primary, always bottled after 1 or 2 weeks, but reading here make me feel encouraged to spend more time. I live in Brasil, my room temp is sigthly higher than the optimal.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Check and compare the gravity of it with the 'sister' batch, then let us know.

Comment: Since I dont't have ways to take a gravity measure, I take some sample off each fermentor by tap and drink it. Everything seems to be very ok, the taste is the same for the 'sister' batches. I'm just impressed with the high taste of alcohol on everyone. Thinking if I've always stoped the fermentation before its done. Thanks you all, jsled, gautier and brewchez.

Comment: Just one thing to say: These 4 batches are the best ever done by me. And the only thing different was the fermentation time. I was drinking 'green beer' all that time! Gave the proper time to the beer to ferment and process all things inside really improved my beer. Thanks, homebrew stack exchange!

Answer (score 1):

It got warm, so the pressure inside the fermentor increased, forcing gas out through the airlock, which you notice as bubbles.

Comment: Nice. But what about the seven others? Why just one is bubbling, is what I'm thinking. If there is something bad this could be related? (i.e: autolises, contamination, etc?) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, it could be contamination inside that one vessel that's creating more activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can always open the lid and carefully take a quick look to see how it's going. Usually the sings of infection are bad smell and white mold spots on the surface. If you don't notice any of that you're good, you can also take a gravity test to see how the yeast is doing and compare it to the other batches...