# lots of gas coming from secondary

Tags: dry-hop, co2

Before I racked to secondary, I had checked the gravity a few days apart to make sure fermentation had completed. After racking to secondary, I waited a few days to let it settle out. The water in the airlock had evened out, so I figured I would be ok to dry hop. Around 3-4 days after dry-hopping, the airlock is going crazy. It bubbles about every second or two. I have been told that I am ok to bottle as planned, but I am concerned that this could lead to bottle bombs. I have had this issue before, and it was also a black ipa. Should I try cold crashing?

Comment: Something similar happened to me once, and everything was ok: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12307/bubbles-restart-after-1-month

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily fermentation causing the bubbles.  Temp changes or other things can cause dissolved CO2 to come out if solution.  That's almost certainly what you're seeing.

Comment: Is it still safe to bottle though while degassing?

Comment: As long as the gravity is consistent, there is no fermentation going on even if you see bubbles.  In that case, it's safe to bottle.

Answer (score 0):

I dry hop all my beers after a few weeks of primary fermentation (sometimes even in the primary fermenter without using a secondary) and every time I will get airlock activity for a few days after. For me its normally the first day after will go crazy but can last awhile.

The beer always tastes great so I wouldn't worry.